# not rendering page on request node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I have this front-end function:

```
 var finalSelValue = ""
    function changeFunc() {
     var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
     var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

   finalSelValue = selectedValue
    fetch('/adminFilter', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            finalSelValue
        })
    })
    }
```

and then this on the backend:

```
  router.post('/adminFilter', auth.ensureAuthenticated, auth.roleCheck('ADMIN'), (req, res) => {

  console.log("filter " + req.body.finalSelValue)

  var query = "select * from tkwdottawa where STATUS = '" + req.body.finalSelValue + "'"
  ibmdb.open(DBCredentials.getDBCredentials(), function(err, conn) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      conn.query(query, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) {
              res.writeHead(404);

          }

          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(rows[i])
          }

          res.render('AdminDash', {
              page_title: "AdminDash",
              data: rows
          });


          conn.close(function() {
              console.log('done adminFilter');

          });
      });
  });


})
```

it is logging the new values properly, where the loop is, but it is not re-rendering the page with the new data! How do I fix this!

Comment: The useful thing about `fetch` is it does not reload the page. If you wish to POST data to the server and reload the entire page with the response then use Javascript to load a `FormData` object and submit it. OR you'll have to grab the data returned by `fetch` and programmatically update the corresponding portion of your page.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might be because you have not fully configured your nodejs application. You should be aware that the **render()** method must have a templating engine that handles views to be available. You can just install one of the below templating engine i.e

1. Pug
2. EJS
3. Handlebars

from Npm repository.

*Just use npm install [pug or ejs]* i suggest this two because they have very easy learning curve

Another solution is to just use **send() or sendFile()** methods. This will send back the data to the client in this case the fetch request, then you can get the response from the *.then callback.*
and update the view from front end script.

Just a note

> Render method is used with a templating engine and mostly is a server side rendering oriented approach